# Can YARN preempt Spark Driver?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Can anyone clarify can or can't YARN preempt Spark Driver because application eat more resources than allowed by it's queue?

This question arised from scenario on prod cluster:

1. CDH 5.12, hadoop 2.6.0, fair scheduller is used
2. Queue A = 50%, Queue B = 25%, Queue C = 25%
3. two apps, say app1 and app2 run in queue B, and has eaten all cluster resources.
4. after a while app3 starts in queue A and claims its resources
5. app1 and app2 kill some of their executors (at least I see `ERROR | SIGTERM handler | org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend | RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM`)
6. app1 prints error message about ApplicationMaster death:
   `ERROR | SIGTERM handler | org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster | RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM`. NM logs just say that driver container was killed: `Stopping container with container Id: app1_driver_containerId`.

I cant find any evidences in documentation that RM can kill application master. Docs say that it asks master politely to free resources, and I they are not freed then it forcely kill containers. Can it kill AM?

Comment: AM is just another container to YARN, why wouldn't it?

Comment: the reason I think it wouldn't is because it's written in hortonworks blog post(https://hortonworks.com/blog/better-slas-via-resource-preemption-in-yarns-capacityscheduler/).
`Instead of killing thus-marked containers immediately to free resources, PreemptionMonitor inside the ResourceManager notifies ApplicationMasters (AM) so that AMs can take advanced actions before ResourceManager itself commits a hard decision`. See also section: "Impact of preemption on application"

Comment: Well, what's your `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.enable` set as, as well as the other properties mentioned there? And are you sure that blog post applys to your version of YARN?

Comment: I've checked for properties mentioned in blog post and haven't find them, while grepping I realised that I was damn wrong about used scheduler! shame on me..., it's fair scheduler, cos `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class` is `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler`. So I've digged to a wrong direction (. I've updated question for other readers. Thanks @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, although there's a ticket to add a configuration to avoid that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-9537.